# How to emulate erf and/or the Normal Inverse function in Moodle?

Tags: software, probability, specific-software

I've just discovered "calculated questions" in Moodle and I'm trying to create a simple one where I would be asking the student to find the probability that an observation from a standard normal population be greater than variable $\left\{z\right\}$.

I then define the range of $\left\{z\right\}$ as $[-3,3]$ with $2$ decimal places.

Now since Moodle doesn't have erf implemented I have been trying to emulate it using Jack D'Aurizio's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1172532), and otherwise Abramowitz and Stegun's first approximation given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions), which results in $$P(z_i> z)\approx \frac{1-\sqrt{1-e^{-0.619495805z^2}}}2$$ for the former, for instance.

I am facing the problem that **Moodle refuses to calculate this when $z$ is less than $2$** (I get the output ***NaN***) and as for the values where it will output something, **the outputs don't seem to depend much on $z$**, I get only four different possible outputs which are $0$, $0.005$, $0.035$ and $0.102$.

Two examples copy-pasted from Moodle:

`1-(1+sqrt(1-exp(-0.619495805*((40.14-11.7)/4.3)^2)))/2 = 0.035`

`1-(1+sqrt(1-exp(-0.619495805*((33.18-13)/4.1)^2)))/2 = 0.102`

Where here $\left\{z\right\}$ was actually calculated via $$\left\{z\right\}=\frac{\left\{x\right\}-\left\{m\right\}}{\left\{s\right\}}$$

Does anyone know how to work around this and get actual proper values for the normal inverse function?

Comment: @user1527 Oh, good point. Now I wonder how it can calculate something in some cases then. Thanks, I'll try fixing that!

Comment: @user1527 Well, you can post this as an answer and I will accept it. It fixed everything. I was really thrown off by the few numerical outputs, which got me thinking that it was a problem of too violent an approximation being done at some point by the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Moodle, but according to [moodle.org](https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Calculated_question_type) you cannot use `^` for powers; instead use `pow({foo}, 2)`.

Comment: Thanks a million! I wonder if we will ever get an explanation why it still computed something in some cases.